# redirecting the request to the same page after upload in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, xmlhttprequest

I am relatively new to upload in MVC, so I have a little clarification. I am performing an ajax upload operation.

The upload operation works absolutely fine, but after the upload, it is **redirecting to a new page which is blank page** which I do not know how to stop it from doing it.
I used EmptyResult as well, but still the same thing is happening.What is it that I am missing?

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
<button onclick="startUpload();">Upload</button>
<br />
<progress id="progressBar" max="100" value="0" />
}
<script>



    function startUpload() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");

        if (fileInput.files.length == 0) {
            alert("Please choose a file");
            return;
        }

        var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
           // alert("in progress");
            var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            progressBar.value = percentComplete;
        };

        xhr.onload = function () {

        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {

            alert("Error! Upload failed. Can not connect to server.");
        };
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        };
        progressBar.value = 0;
        xhr.open("POST", "/Home/Index", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application / json');
        xhr.send(fileInput.files[0]);
    }
</script>


    [HttpPost]
    public EmptyResult  Index(FormCollection frm)
    {
        // Create JSON Response
        var jsonData = new
        {
            status = "success",
            message = "message"
        };
        return null;
                }
```

Comment: Add `type="button" to the `<button>` element so it does not submit the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the event value on your button's onclick function call in order to manipulate the event handling later like this:

```
<button onclick="startUpload(event);">Upload</button>
```

Then in your javascript, you can ask it to ignore the default event handling (submit the form this case):

```
 function startUpload(event) {
    //do all those stuff

    //event.preventDefault() should handle most of the browsers
    //but for better compatibility, it's 3 lines here
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
    return false;
 }
```